# Java | What is the /** */ for?

Tags: java, comments

I was wondering what the `/** hello */` in Java was for. The only reason I currently use them is because I like how it shows up blue in Eclipse and I'm to lazy to change colors in my preferences. I've noticed when I automatically add stuff like `serialVersionUID`'s it puts `/** * */` right above it, but what is it actually for?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

Comment: @freakshow1217 While I generally agree with that statement for many questions... in this case, what would you suggest he used as a google search term? Googling for "/**" or "java /**" aren't particularly productive and if he knew to google for "javadoc" he wouldn't have needed to. Is there some search term he should have thought of that I'm also not thinking of here?

Comment: You can quite often get useful results just searching for the names of the special characters. I get a useful answer if I search for "Java slash two asterisks."

Comment: @resueman cool, I didn't know google would manage that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such comment as

```
/** hello */
```

is a  **JavaDocs** comment, means that if you hover the element to whom you attached this comment & pressed **Ctrl+Q** (in *IntelliJ IDEA* e.g), you shall get your `"hello"` comment as a definition. It's like if you're building your own documentation (for that function or property).

[image: JavaDoc]

While

`/* regular comment */`

is just a regular comment.

Comment: thanks, when I try to google it, it just seems to search it without the non-alpha-numerical characters.